# Responsive design does not seem to work perfectly

Tags: android, html, css, responsive

I am having problems with the responsivness of webpage. I used a couple of websites and Chrome's dev tools to determine the problem but they all show it properly. Once I open the page on my phone (Samsung Galxy S5) the background becomes white and only the text can be seen. Here is my media query:

```
@media (max-width: 768px) {
    body {
        background-image: url(images/bg-img.jpg);
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-attachment: fixed;
        background-size: cover;
        -webkit-background-size: cover;
        -moz-background-size: cover;
        margin: 0;
    }
}
```

And here is the whole code: https://jsfiddle.net/Manny5980/uwa4np7v/

Answer (score 0):

Alert will not work in webview, you should use `document.write`

Answer (score 0):

please visit

https://responsivedesign.is/develop/browser-feature-support/media-queries-for-common-device-breakpoints

/* Samsung Galaxy S5 ----------- */

@media only screen and (min-device-width: 360px) and 
(max-device-height: 640px) and 
(orientation : landscape) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 3){

/* Styles */

}

@media only screen and (min-device-width: 360px) and (max-device-height: 640px) and (orientation : portrait) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 3){

/* Styles */

}

Comment: I tried several of the options provided. Some cut the background image, others show the page white again.